# Value of type 'MKMapItem' has no member 'website` in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapitem

I am creating an app where I have annotation view and when you click on the annotation view it does not show the annotation view website url on the view controller `DetailsView` please have a look at my code and help me solve it by showing the website URL of the annotation view places.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

protocol UserLocationDelegate {
    func userLocation(latitude: Double, longitude: Double)
}

class NearMeMapViewController: ARViewController, ARDataSource, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var nearMeIndexSelected = NearMeIndexTitle()
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    var nearMeARAnnotations = [ARAnnotation]()

    var nearMeRequests = [NearMeRequest]()
    var delegate: UserLocationDelegate!

    var place: Place?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = nearMeIndexSelected.indexTitle

        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLHeadingFilterNone
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        self.dataSource = self
        self.headingSmoothingFactor = 0.05
        self.maxVisibleAnnotations = 30

        getNearMeIndexSelectedLocation()
    }

    func getNearMeIndexSelectedLocation() {

        let nearMeRequest = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        nearMeRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = nearMeIndexSelected.indexTitle

        let nearMeregion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(self.locationManager.location!.coordinate, 250, 250)
        nearMeRequest.region = nearMeregion

        let nearMeSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: nearMeRequest)

        nearMeSearch.start{(response: MKLocalSearchResponse?, error: Error?) in

            for requestItem in (response?.mapItems)! {

                let nearMeIndexRequest = NearMeRequest()
                nearMeIndexRequest.name = requestItem.name
                nearMeIndexRequest.coordinate = requestItem.placemark.coordinate
                nearMeIndexRequest.address = requestItem.placemark.addressDictionary?["FormattedAddressLines"] as! [String]
                nearMeIndexRequest.street = requestItem.placemark.addressDictionary?["Street"] as! String!
                nearMeIndexRequest.city = requestItem.placemark.addressDictionary?["City"] as! String
                nearMeIndexRequest.state = requestItem.placemark.addressDictionary?["State"] as! String
                nearMeIndexRequest.zip = requestItem.placemark.addressDictionary?["ZIP"] as! String
                nearMeIndexRequest.phone = requestItem.phoneNumber
                nearMeIndexRequest.website = requestItem.website // This is where the error is at.

                self.nearMeRequests.append(nearMeIndexRequest)
                print(requestItem.placemark.name)
            }

            for nearMe in self.nearMeRequests {
                let annotation = NearMeAnnotation(nearMeRequest: nearMe)
                self.nearMeARAnnotations.append(annotation)
                self.setAnnotations(self.nearMeARAnnotations)
            }
        }
    }

    func ar(_ arViewController: ARViewController, viewForAnnotation: ARAnnotation) -> ARAnnotationView {

        let annotationView = NearMeARAnnotationView(annotation: viewForAnnotation)
        annotationView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 50)

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapBlurButton(_:)))
        annotationView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        return annotationView
    }

    func tapBlurButton(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        if let annotationView = sender.view as? NearMeARAnnotationView {

            if let detailsVc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsViewController") as? DetailsViewController {

                detailsVc.annotation = annotationView.annotation
                detailsVc.place = Place(location: (locationManager.location)!,
                                        reference: "",
                                        name: annotationView.annotationNameLabel.text ?? "",
                                        address: annotationView.annotationAddressLabel.text ?? "",
                                        phoneNumber: annotationView.phoneNumber.text ?? "",
                                        website: annotationView.website.text ?? "")

                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailsVc, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a website property on `MKMapItem`. There is a `url` property however that should contain the website associated with the location.

Here is what Apple's docs say about the map item's [url](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapitem/1452746-url) property.

> If there is a relevant URL associated with the location, such as a URL for a business at the location, use this property to specify that value.

Your line of code:

```
nearMeIndexRequest.website = requestItem.website
```

should be changed to:

```
nearMeIndexRequest.website = requestItem.url.absoluteString
```

Comment: I try to implement by the `url` property.. But, I got stuck so I just did it that way and thats why I am here for you guys to help me out. Can you show me the right way to implement it the right way with the `url` property.

Comment: Also, I don't want to set a hard-coded value. I want to do like the way I did with phoneNumber... Whenever user clicks on the annotation View it shows that places website url on the next view controller.

Comment: Do you want a URL or a String for the website?

Comment: then I change this from `var website :String!` to `var website: Url?` but still it does not work..

Comment: I want the URL of that place website.

Comment: Then use `requestItem.url`.

Comment: then I change this from var website :String! to var website: Url? but still it does not work.

Comment: `Url` is not a Swift type. You need to use `URL`.

Comment: Yeah I did that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158634/discussion-between-justin-s-and-naturaln0va).

Comment: If you want a string you can access the url's string like this: `requestItem.url?.absoluteString`.